# Graph shortest-path with storing checked vertexes

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, breadth-first-search

I know that time complexity of shortest path via BFS is `O(V+E)`. But I have found one of algorithm's implementations on Python which looks like this.

```
def search(name):
   search_queue = deque()
   search_queue += graph[name]  # graph is a dict<string: list of strings>

   searched = []
   while search_queue:
      person = search_queue.popleft()
      if person not in searched:
         if some_checking(person):
            return True
         else:
            search_queue += graph[person]
            searched.append(person)

   return False
```

In the outer loop we traverse through each vertex in the graph and each iteration we check whether the vertex has been already visited. Searching will take O(N) operations since `searched` is a list. Am I right that time complexity is `O(V^2)` in this implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Searching if the node was already visited can take up to `O(V)` and it is done `O(V)` times. This code is `O(V^2)`.

It can be easily improved by changing the data structure used to store visited nodes. Changing from list to set, will make this code works in `O(V + E)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! One more question, just to make sure, `O(V)` means that we go through each vertex and `O(E)` means how many appends to `search_queue` will be performed, am I right?

Comment: For `O(V)` you are correct, for `O(E)` it means the algorithm also depends linearly on the number of edges. In this case it is noted in the line `search_queue += graph[person]`. The cost of this line is proportional to the number of neighbors, but the sum of all neighbors it less than 2 * E.

Comment: Yea, by the phrase _how many appends to search_queue_ I mean exactly the line `search_queue += graph[person]`. The last words `O(2 * E)` is about undirected graphs?  Because for directed graph it will be exactly `O(E)`. 

P.S. Sorry for such primitive questions, I just try to make it clear.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate it.